# Susy: override bleed() at breakpoint

Tags: css, sass, susy, susy-sass

How do I undo the bleed-x() mixin at a smaller breakpoint so box4 (the yellow box) in example 2 goes back in between the purple columns and doesn't wrap to the next line.

```
 .story4 {
  @include bleed-x();
  @include span(2);
  background: yellow;
  height: 80px;
  @include breakpoint($small) {
    @include span(8 last);
  }
}
```

Codepen:
http://codepen.io/meijioro/pen/aBdWyO

Answer (score 0):

Bleed is a combination of negative margins and positive padding. Reset both to `0` to override:

```
@include breakpoint($small) {
  @include span(8 last);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

In general, I try to avoid breakpoint overrides by limiting the original application. Something more like this:

```
.story4 {
  @include span(2);
  background: yellow;
  height: 80px;

  // use your own tools to create max-width breakpoints...
  // this limits the bleed, so we don't have to override it later.
  @media (max-width: $small) { 
    @include bleed-x();
  }

  @include breakpoint($small) {
    @include span(8 last);
  }
}
```